# Incidence Raw data structure for iNext package / error: Error in yi[i]:(nT - 1) : NA/NaN argument

Tags: r, list, dataframe, alpha, inext

I have a presence/absence data matrix: 24 species as rows and 6 Locations as columns. If a species is present at a location it has the value 1, if it is absent it has the value 0.
Now i want to do diversity analyses with the iNext function and estimateD function using this data. In the description of the iNext package it says:

> Incidence-raw data (datatype="incidence_raw"): for each assemblage, input data for a reference
> sample consisting of a species-by-sampling-unit matrix; each element in the raw matrix is 1 for a
> detection, and 0 otherwise. When there are N assemblages, input data consist of N lists of raw
> matrices, and each matrix is a species-by-sampling-unit matrix.

I managed to convert my data frame to a list using:

```
x <- as.list(data.frame)
```

But then i get following error when computing the iNext or estimateD function:

```
Error in yi[i]:(nT - 1) : NA/NaN argument
```

first i tried to only use the data frame as input for the iNext function, which did not work out. Then i tried as.list() function, where the data seems to be in good shape, but the above mentioned error always occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. I installed an older version where I get a different error message:

```
1: In EstiBootComm.Sam(c(nT, y)) :
  This site has only one species. Estimation is not robust.
```

but it worked.

See here: https://github.com/JohnsonHsieh/iNEXT/issues/75

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).